# Is there a canonical way to handle inserting records that might contain duplicates?

Tags: orientdb

I am using OrientDB to graph a social network.  Vertices are unique-indexed by `user_id`.  When inserting new vertices, I might encounter potential duplicates.  For example, `user_id(1)` has friends: `user_id(0)`...`user_id(5)`...`user_id(n)`.  That same user `1`, might also have followers that intersect, for example, `user_id(5)` might be both in the set of `friends` and `followers`.

So, I insert the root user vertex, and then grab all the ID's of friends, as well as the ID's of followers, and then insert those in a batch operation.

My question is, when inserting vertices, is there a canonical method to insert new records that accounts for duplicates?

Given the structure of my application, I can think of a couple of methods:

1)  Creating each new user vertex with the following:

```
create vertex User content {user_node}
```

Prior to each insertion, I check the `user_id` against a secondary-index contained in a Redis database.  I use the `@rid` field for subsequent creation of edges.  The Redis store contains a hash-index with fields `user_id` and values `@rid`, so I can populate `@rid` this way.

This has the advantage of keeping OrientDB access down.  Also, accessing Redis is likely quite a bit faster than accessing OrientDB, and the time complexity of getting the value of a hash field is O(1); therefore, I'm thinking that, even though I'm querying two databases for each operation, I'm still coming out ahead (maybe).  However, in the event of divergence between OrientDB and the secondary-index, duplicate records would raise `ORecordDuplicatedException`.  I can catch this exception at the application level, but then I have `@rid` issues.  I am using the `@rid` field because, according to the OrientDB docs, this is the fastest way to access a record.

2)  Update/Upsert for each insertion:

```
update User content {user_node} upsert where user_id = 1
```

This would, I think, keep all the error catching and duplicate detection on the database-side.  Coming from Neo4j, `MERGE` operations like this are a bit more expensive than `CREATE`; does the same apply to OrientDB?

Are there any other insert methods that I'm missing?  Is there a best solution here?  Thanks!

Comment: There are any limitations on UPSERT (see the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Update.html#limitations-of-
the-upsert-clause).
Obviously upsert should be more expensive than create.